# How to define multiple ini settings using php command line?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-arguments, ini

I am trying to allow the `allow_url_fopen` and `rename` functions temporarily for a script. I can do it with just one function, but not both.

Something like this:

```
php -d allow_url_fopen=on rename=on <file>
```

I'm using PHP 5.6

## Update

Apparently `rename()` is in the `disable_functions` in my php.ini file (whereas `allow_url_fopen` is turned off outside of that), so I'm assuming the `-d` option doesn't change the settings for the `disable_functions` directive.

Therefore, the original question still stands, and a new one:

**Is it possible to enable a disabled function with the command line tool? Or would I have to redefine the whole `disable_functions` directive (if possible)?**

## Update Two

This works for my situation:

```
php -d disable_functions=fn1,fn2,etc -r 'ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "1");' <file> <args>
```

You cannot use `ini_set()` to change the `disable_functions` directive. If there is another directive in your php.ini file that cannot be changed by `ini_set()` then I don't know how to solve that. My issue has been resolved, although the original question hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: Maybe try -d for each option.

Comment: @mkaatman I've tried that. =/

Comment: After screwing around with this a bit, I could only get -d to work in conjunction with -r. It seems like if you pass a file in it completely ignores -d. Maybe you could pass in a file and an ini file with the settings you want to pass in. Here are the relevant docs anyway: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: @mkaatman I've tried `php -B 'ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "1"); ini_set("rename", "1");'` and `php -r 'ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "1"); ini_set("rename", "1");'` to no avail. See my updated question, though.

Comment: Are you stuck on a host that won't allow you to change your php.ini?

Comment: @mkaatman I haven't gotten around to seeing if they'd be willing to change it yet, so I'm trying to see if it's possible without resorting to that.

Comment: What do you get if you run: `php -d allow_url_fopen=1 -r 'echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen")."\n";'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must only define a `-d OPTION` block for each setting you like to define.

You need to run:

`php -d allow_url_fopen=on -d rename=on <file>`